# 4-20mA circuit IC troubleshooting

Tags: 4-20ma

I have two pressure transmitters that I am converting current 4-20mA signals to analog voltage 0-5Vdc signals.  Both circuits should be identical, except in footprint.  The IC is [RCV420JP](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/rcv420).  On one circuit I am reading 0.2V on the 0-5V outlet "AI0" and on the other, I was reading about -0.4V.  I cut the trace on the analog output of the second IC (the one reading negative) and it began to read -12V.

I have verified the 12V and -12V voltages are good to the ICs.  The Ground connection is good.  I checked and the voltage on the IC's sensor input "IN+" was 0.34V.

The pressure transmitters [sensor](https://assets.omega.com/pdf/test-and-measurement-equipment/pressure/pressure-transducers/PX119.pdf) have worked on breakout boards I bought for 4-20mA conversion so I know they are functional.  Even if they didn't work I would expect the analog output of the IC to be 0-5Vdc as the datasheet specified. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I have done incorrectly?  I posted this on texas instruments forum a while back, had another error at this point, lack of bipolar supply, but info is still valuable. [post](https://e2e.ti.com/support/amplifiers-group/amplifiers/f/amplifiers-forum/1047710/rcv420-reference-circuit-configuration?tisearch=e2e-sitesearch&keymatch=RCV420JP#)

[image: circuit schematic]

[image: footprint]

Comment: where is the sensor in the schematic diagram?

Comment: I added the sensor datasheet, but it doesn't show the circuit diagram.

Comment: the sheet you added indicates that the sensor can output 0-5 V

Comment: There are versions that have a built in analog converter this is not one of them

Comment: Have you tried swapping out the RCV420 in case it's been damaged? It's very easy to apply excessive current to the input, for example, as there is no built-in input overload protection. Probably worth socketing the chips.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany when you say input, you are referring to the IN+?

Comment: Yes. Excessive current between either +IN or -IN and ground can damage the chip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should do is to connect a 12mA current source instead of the transducer and see if it will work. The current source could be based on the 3-pin LM334.

If that works, then the sensor connection is faulty or the sensor doesn't work. If it doesn't work, then you've killed the converter chip, most likely by letting excessive current  flow into `-IN`.

There are several problems I see:

1. The power supply design seems to use MAX765 switchers directly feeding the analog +/-12V supplies. **This is problematic**. You'd probably need to add LDO linear regulators as the 2nd stage to reduce ripple, and add a ferrite bead between the switcher and the LDO.
2. The switchers use an electrolytic capacitor on the output. They should also have a ceramic capacitor.
3. The pulsed current loop in the switcher has gratuitously high-impedance and large area. It should be tight and use fills not traces for minimum impedance. Perhaps the datasheet has a good layout example?
4. The layout proposed seems to be 2 signal, 1 power layer, and 1 ground plane. Wasting a whole layer just for power *traces* is wasteful: instead, use non-overlapping power planes to distribute the supplies in a low-impedance fashion, and provide some additional low-parasitic distributed capacitance between the power plane and the ground plane.

The application circuit you've implemented looks OK to me. The schematic symbol you've drawn is *awful* at communicating the function of the chip though. You may wish to redraw it similarly to what's in the datasheet. The function of the schematic is not to be a glorified netlist, but to clearly state the function principle of the circuit.

When drawing in KiCad, don't use global nets as power symbols. Use the power symbols themselves, by pressing the `P` keyboard shortcut.

Also note that the sensor needs only **two** wires: 8-30V supply - you provided 12V, that's fine, and the current sink - provided by the -IN of the receiver chip. Ground can be connected to the shield on *one side* of the cable only.

Below, I've re-drawn the schematic as-if I was drawing that circuit :)

[image: Schematic of the single sensor signal conditioner]

In practice, the 12V outputs should be circuit limited - at least to the extent needed not to blow the input resistors in the expensive I-V converter chips when there's a short to ground.

I've probably set the current limit a bit high, it should be 26mA, giving R301=R302=24Ω,0.5%. The current source will survive a short to ground for a while, but will eventually run somewhat hot.

When multiple channels are used, they should all run from the same reference, to minimize drift between channels.

[image: Schematic of a protected two-channel signal conditioner]

An example layout that would be reasonable for that application is below. A two-layer layout would work as long as you'd be able to route the +/-12V supplies without interference.

I have not drawn the switcher and LDO, even though their layout is critical as well, and your existing layout will unnecessarily under-perform (you pay for that PCB, might as well get all the performance you can from it!).

[image: 2 Layer example board layout]

[KiCad 6 schematics and PCB are available for download](https://gist.github.com/KubaO/f2f36826626221ffbed1f1fe439ca9fe)